# Unable To Tap UIToolbar Button Item

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am having a problem interacting with the bar button items on my `UIToolbar` which is subclassed. Basically, My `UIToolbar` is displayed, but I can't tap any of the bar button items on it.

When the view loads, I have the `UIToolbar` initially hidden using this code:

```
 - (void) viewDidLoad { 
    _cardToolbar.hidden = YES;
 }
```

Then, when the user taps once on the view, a method to show the `UIToolbar` is called, This is my method code:

```
- (void) showToolbar {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.4
                     animations:^(void)
     {
         CGRect toolbarFrame = self.cardToolbar.frame;
         toolbarFrame.origin.y = 372; // moves Toolbar onto screen
         self.cardToolbar.frame = toolbarFrame;
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         self.cardToolbar.hidden = NO;
     }];
}
```

Everything up to here works flawlessly. I should also mention, I guess, that my `UIToolbar` is on top of a `UIScrollview` in the view that it is being displayed. the problem is that I can't tap any of the buttons on it!

Any ideas as to why I can interact with the bar button items on my `UIToolbar`?

Comment: _cardToolbar.hidden=No; try like this

Comment: The toolbar is probably behind the scrollview. Either adjust the scrollview's frame to be above the toolbar or bring the toolbar to the front of the scrollview.

Comment: Check if the actions are set for tool bar items or not. Without having the action set for the tool bar item, you cannot tap it.

Comment: After animation over put tabbar.enable = yes; and also userInteraction = yes;

Comment: It seems I had multiple problems. @rmaddy It was behind the scroolview, so I fixed that part of the problem but it still does not call the action tied to the bar button items.

Comment: @Anjaneyulu your suggestion lets me tap the buttons now but the actions are not being called, any ideas?